# idAttribute setting ignored when doing id fetch

Tags: backbone.js, titanium-alloy

I have a model defined that specifies the identity column in the Events.js model file:

```
exports.definition = {
    config: {
        columns: {
            "eventId": "string PRIMARY KEY",
            "eventDate": "string",
            "eventName": "string",
            "street1": "string",
            "city": "string",
            "state": "string",
            "zip": "string"
        },
        adapter: {
            type: "sql",
            collection_name: "Events",
            idAttribute:"eventId",
            db_name:"_Fundraising"
        }
    },
    extendModel: function(Model) {
        _.extend(Model.prototype, {
            // extended functions and properties go here
        });

        return Model;
    },
    extendCollection: function(Collection) {
        _.extend(Collection.prototype, {
            // extended functions and properties go here
        });

        return Collection;
    }
};
```

It creates the database file correctly, however when I try to retrieve from the database using a specific ID, the SQL created is using the default `alloy_id` identifier instead of `eventId` as specified in the config.

```
var events = Alloy.createCollection('Events');
events.fetch({ id : "62243" });
```

Full error message:

```
2014-10-21 12:22:03.223 Fundraising[53498:946130] [ERROR] A SQLite database error occurred on database 
*** file path removed ***
: Error Domain=com.plausiblelabs.pldatabase Code=3 
"An error occured parsing the provided SQL statement." UserInfo=0x7ae7b660 
{com.plausiblelabs.pldatabase.error.vendor.code=1, NSLocalizedDescription=An error occured parsing the provided SQL statement., 
com.plausiblelabs.pldatabase.error.query.string=SELECT * FROM Events WHERE alloy_id = "62243", com.plausiblelabs.pldatabase.error.vendor.string=no such column: alloy_id} (SQLite #1: no such column: alloy_id) (query: 'SELECT * FROM Events WHERE alloy_id = "62243"')
```

How do I adjust my config so idAttribute is properly acknowledged?

Comment: more code, please :)

Comment: I'm not sure what else to add. That's all that's needed to do the fetch.

Comment: what does the *rest* of the error say?

Comment: btw, try and put `idAttribute` under `config` level, rather than under `adapter` and see if that solves it.

Comment: Moving it out of the adapter level causes the `alloy_id` column to be added. Having it in both places does not solve the error.

Comment: you may simply need to recreate the table, see [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20569728/547020).

Comment: The post you referenced is not doing a fetch by ID like I am. Also, I am completely removing the database each time I make a change so that it is recreated when I run my test.

Answer (score 0):

When using the fetch function, instead of using id, use eventId. That way the correct column is queried.

Answer (score 0):

as you have defined idAttribute in your model (Events.js), try this:

```
var events = Alloy.createCollection('Events');
events.fetch({ idAttribute : "62243" });
```

it should read the value of your idAttribute in the adaptor section of the model, because in build/android/assets/alloy/sync/sql.js you can find this

```
...(o+=" WHERE "+(t.idAttribute?t.idAttribute:ALLOY_ID_DEFAULT)+" = "+(_.isString(i.id)?'"'+i.id+'"':i.id))...
```

so if there is no idAttribute in your parameter array, it uses the alloy_id